# Ember.js migration from 1.8.1 to version 2.+

Tags: ember.js

We have a quite big application built on the version 1.8.1. We would like to migrate to version 2.0 or higher. We have a few guestions:

- Does exist some step-by-step manual how to do it?
- Can we use 2 different versions of ember in the same time? Because of continuous migration...

We would like to avoid overwriting of the whole application...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you to update the ember. and keep deprecation warnings open. Then you can try investigating each warning one by one and update the code with the new syntax.

This guide can be very useful : [Upgrade to ember 2.x step-by step](https://www.emberscreencasts.com/meta_guide_to_upgrading_ember)

Since Ember uses global window scope, it will result in conflicts and its not advisable to use two versions of ember.

Comment: The post linked covers the process pretty well. My advise is to go from point release to point release so as not to be overwhelmed by deprecations. So first 1.9, 1.10, 1.11, etc.

Comment: Feel free to upvote the answer so that others get benefited. :)

Comment: Thank you. But it looks like a lot a lot of work :( Our app is big. Can we use 2 different versions of ember in the same time?

Comment: That would be a lot of overhead, it will get difficult to find out which version is giving error. its never advisable to use two versions. Also mark this as answer if it helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's *possible* to load different Ember versions based on which route you are on, but I really don't recommend doing that, as you lose all the benefits of having a Single Page App (apps will load again when you transition between them), and you end up doing significantly more work for yourself, with more opportunities to screw up. I'd follow locks' advice and upgrade the app step by step, testing as you go.